# Создание файла на сетевом диске php

Tags: php

**Задача:** создать файл на **сетевом диске**

Путь к папке на сетевом диске: *//nk-web/folder/* (nk-web - имя сервера; тоже сетевой)

Функция **is_dir** с этим путём возвращает false (с любым написанием, *\\nk-web\folder\*, *\\nk-web\folder*, *//nk-web/folder/*, *//nk-web/folder/*). Но если вставить \nk-web\folder\ в проводник компьютера, то открывается нужная сетевая папка.

При создании файла с именем '123.txt':

```
$f = fopen('//nk-web/folder/123.txt', 'a');
$text = 'test test';
fwrite($f, $test);
fclose($f);
```

Формируется файл в корне ЛОКАЛЬНОГО сервера с названием '_VL4NL~P.txt' и содержимым 'test test'.

1. Почему не получается создать файл в сетевой папке?
2. Почему файл создаётся в корне локального сервера?
3. Почему файл создаётся со странным названием, но корректным содержимым?

Comment: символическую ссылку сделайте на сетевую папку лучше в нужной проекте и с ней работайте

Comment: @teran создал ярлык, переименовал на test. В коде прописываю: scandir('путь/test'), результат - false.

Comment: ярлык и символическая ссылка это разные вещи. `mklink /d` под виндой и `ln -s` по *никс

Comment: @teran , нет возможности открывать консоль как администратор, т.к. не наделён такими правами. есть ещё предложения, как можно попробовать реализовать?

Comment: используйте `realpath` совместно с `is_dir` для определения является ли указанный путь папкой. `is_dir` под Windows работает не так как под Unix и не дает 100% гарантии. Примерно вот так `( realpath( trim($folderName) ) !== false AND is_dir( realpath( trim($folderName) ) ) )`

Comment: @ФеоктистПупырышкин realpath вернул false. Причём на локальном сервере есть сетевая папка. Если к ней прописать локальный путь, то realpath возвращает путь к папке, а если написать сетевой путь (к этой же папке), то realpath возвращает false. Но из проводника доступ есть как по локальному, так и по сетевому пути. Посмотрел в правах у папки есть служебный пользователь, но как зайти под служебным пользователем через php?..

Comment: Вам нужно два скрипта `php` - первый запускает внутри себя через `exec` консольную Windows-утилиту `runas`. А утилита уже через свои параметры запускает из-под другого пользователя второй `php`-скрипт который и делает то, что Вам нужно. Но вообще странно, если Вы читаете папку из-под пользователя под которым залогинились, то и скрипт запускаемый из-под него тоже это должен делать. Или у Вас `php`-скрипт не консольный и запускается вообще на Windows-сервере из под какого-нибудь `IIS`? Тогда там скорее всего вообще все права для запускаемых скриптов порезаны.