# Обращение к ярлыку из php

Tags: php, ярлыки

В папке test лежит ярлык на другую папку, ярлык называется help-me.
Если делаю scandir:

```
echo scandir('путь к test');
```

то на страницу выводится название ярлыка 'help-me.lnk' .

Как можно из кода сделать scandir этого ярлыка?

```
scandir('путь к test/help-me');
```

и

```
scandir('путь к test/help-me.lnk');
```

возвращают false

Comment: `PHP` не умеет работать с файлами с расширением `.lnk` (ярлыками Windows). Но вы можете создать symlink через PHP. И если вы хотите работать с lnk файлами, то вы явно делаете что то не то.

Comment: @zerxa не могу создавать символическую ссылку, т.к. не являюсь администратором. при открытии консоли как админ просит логие и пароль, коих у меня нет... ни прав ни пароля...

Comment: А что конкретно вам нужно, прочитать/получить каталог из этой директории?

Comment: @zetxa вообще задача - создать файл на сетевом диске. но из кода почему-то не вижу сетевую папку. описывал более подробно вот тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1571990/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-php

Comment: Попробуйте из `PHP` проверить есть ли у вас доступ в эту папку через `if (chdir( $folderName) ) {} else {}`. Попробуйте из `PHP` создать там файл по полному пути (могут быть права на чтение папки, но на запись отсутствовать) через `file_put_contents` и посмотрите, не вернет ли ошибок `PHP`. Помните, что пути к сетевым ресурсам в Windows начинаются с `\\<компьютер>\папка`, и что символ ` \ ` в `PHP` в строковых переменных нужно экранировать еще одним ` \ `